# Import local npm package using scope

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, package.json, tsconfig

My monorepo:

```
/app1
  package.json
/app2
  package.json
/shared
  package.json
```

The `shared/package.json` has `"name": "@company/shared"`.

The app projects' `package.json` files have dependecy `"@company/shared": "file:../shared"`.

When referencing the shared code, I want a "short" style, which is also less liable to break when things are moved around:

```
import { foo } from "@company/shared"
```

But that doesn't work, so I have to do this::

```
import { foo } from "../../../../../shared/src/something"
```

I fiddled with both `package.json` and `tsconfig.json` without success.

How do I set that up?

Answer (score 3):

You should link your shared package to your dependent packages using npm-link.

```sh
cd ~/shared                 # go into the package directory
npm link                    # creates global link
cd ~/app1                   # go into some other package directory.
npm link @company/shared    # link-install the package
```

this will tell npm to install the package from the shared folder, and update with any changes made to the original package

for more info see https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link.html

EDIT:
I have realized only now that you are planning to upload the shared package to the server. in that case you may use the `module-alias` package, https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias

this will allow you to make imports such as `const sharedModule = require('@shared/moduleName');`

EDIT #2:
For typescript, use https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths

Comment: What is the difference between link (what you've proposed) and relative file imports (what I tried) - they seem to overlap?

Comment: npm link will tell your package to install the linked dependency to your node_modules from the path on your computer, while relative imports will just tell node to load the module from the folder at runtime

Comment: I also notice that link will not touch the package.json which means when I deploy it would break (unless someone remembers to run it on the production server... so not such a portable solution)

Comment: @lonix sorry didn't realise you are asking about aliases, see my edit

Comment: Thanks for the update, looks like a cool package... is it the only way to accomplish this?

Comment: @lonix for the matter of fact I'm not sure, but for typescript you will ned to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths instead.

Answer (score 3):

Actually there is a part missing from my code above.

The shared project needs to export the shared stuff in an `index.js` (i.e. a "barrel" file) and [reference that](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json.html#main) in the `package.json`:

```
"main": "dist/index.js",
"types": "dist/index.d.ts",
```

And then the alias import style works.